# Как определить кодировку?

Tags: delphi, кодировка, delphi-7

Уважаемые программисты, прошу помочь определить кодировку `=?koi8-r?B?3NTPINTFzcE=?=`
на первый взгляд koi8-r, однако, если я не ошибаюсь - там только русские буквы.
попытался перевести при помощи [сайта](http://forall.ru-board.com/Svarga/koi_win_iso_utf_decoder.html). но безрезультатно. Один знакомый программист предположил, что это koi8-r выведенная в windows-1251. Однако, пока мои попытки перевода успехом не заканчивались(

Comment: это Base64 (то что идет за B?). а потом уже koi8-r.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov значит мне сначала нужно перевести из Base64 в Koi8-R?

Comment: сначала раскодируете base64, получаете строку в кои, которую уже переводите в нужную кодировку. в indy есть декодер IdDecoderMIME, воспользуйтесь им.

Comment: @@Yura Ivanov Спасибо, так и сделал - получилось)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный код используется (обычно) в теме письма. По-крайней мере формат для него подходит.
Как раскодировать (пример для PHP):

```
$string = '=?koi8-r?B?3NTPINTFzcE=?=';
$pattern = '@(?<=\=\?)'
         . '(?<encoding>[a-zA-Z0-9-]++)\?'
         . 'B\?(?<base64_string>[a-zA-Z0-9=]++)'
         . '(?=\?\=)@u';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $m);
if ($m['encoding'] && $m['base64_string']) {
    echo iconv($m['encoding'], 'UTF-8', base64_decode($m['base64_string']));
}
// это тема
```

**update**: проморгал тэги... **[Вот здесь](http://ideone.com/SG0azw)** можно раскодировать онлайн с помощью этого же скрипта.
Нажмите "Редактировать" (или "fork").
Вставьте строку, которую нужно раскодировать, в переменную $string.
Нажмите "Run".
**3NTPINTFzcE=** декодируем из base64 и переводим из KOI8-R в UTF-8 (если нужно)

В stdout будет результат декодирования

Comment: Даже с учётом неучёта :) тегов хорошо бы помнить золотое правило: "решая проблему с помощью регекспов ты создаёшь себе ещё одну проблему". 

P.S. для PHP: [`iconv_mime_decode()`](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv-mime-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант я использую для определения кодировки текста, взятого из интернет страниц и почтовых сообщений с неопределенной кодировкой:

```
function IsKOI8REncodedString(S:String):Boolean;
var
i:integer;
LU,LL:integer;
EX:String;
begin
result:=false;
S:=TRIM(S);
if S='' then exit;

EX:='АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя';
LU:=1;LL:=1;

for i:=1 to length(S) do
if pos(S[i],EX)>0 then
begin
if S[i]=ansiuppercase(S[i]) then LU:=LU+1;
if S[i]=ansilowercase(S[i]) then LL:=LL+1;
end;

if (LU/LL)>1 then result:=true else Result:=false;
end;
```

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function IsUTF8EncodedString(S:String):Boolean;
begin
if s='' then result:=false else
if length(UTF8Decode(S))=0 then Result:=false else result:=true;
end;
```

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
function IsBase64EncodedString(S:String):Boolean;
var
i:integer;
EX:String;
begin
EX:=#$00+#$01+#$02+#$03+#$04+#$05+#$06+#$07+#$08+#$09+#$0A+#$0B+#$0C+#$0D+#$0E+#$0F+#$10+#$11+#$12+#$13+#$14+#$15+#$16+#$17+#$18+#$19+#$1A+#$1B
+#$1C+#$1D+#$1E+#$1F+#$20+#$21+#$22+#$23+#$24+#$25+#$26+#$27+#$28+#$29+#$2A+#$2C+#$2D+#$2E+#$3A+#$3B+#$3C+#$3E+#$3F+#$40+#$5B+#$5C+#$5D
+#$5E+#$5F+#$60+#$7B+#$7C+#$7D+#$7E+#$7F+#$80+#$81+#$82+#$83+#$84+#$85+#$86+#$87+#$88+#$89+#$8A+#$8B+#$8C+#$8D+#$8E+#$8F+#$90+#$91+#$92
+#$93+#$94+#$95+#$96+#$97+#$98+#$99+#$9A+#$9B+#$9C+#$9D+#$9E+#$9F+#$A0+#$A1+#$A2+#$A3+#$A4+#$A5+#$A6+#$A7+#$A8+#$A9+#$AA+#$AB
+#$AC+#$AD+#$AE+#$AF+#$B0+#$B1+#$B2+#$B3+#$B4+#$B5+#$B6+#$B7+#$B8+#$B9+#$BA+#$BB+#$BC+#$BD+#$BE+#$BF+#$C0+#$C1+#$C2+#$C3
+#$C4+#$C5+#$C6+#$C7+#$C8+#$C9+#$CA+#$CB+#$CC+#$CD+#$CE+#$CF+#$D0+#$D1+#$D2+#$D3+#$D4+#$D5+#$D6+#$D7+#$D8+#$D9+#$DA
+#$DB+#$DC+#$DD+#$DE+#$DF+#$E0+#$E1+#$E2+#$E3+#$E4+#$E5+#$E6+#$E7+#$E8+#$E9+#$EA+#$EB+#$EC+#$ED+#$EE+#$EF+#$F0+#$F1
+#$F2+#$F3+#$F4+#$F5+#$F6+#$F7+#$F8+#$F9+#$FA+#$FB+#$FC+#$FD+#$FE+#$FF;

Result:=true;
s:=TRIM(ansireplacestr(ansireplacestr(S,#13,''),#10,''));
if length(S)/2<>trunc(length(S)/2) then Result:=false else
for i:=1 to length(EX) do if pos(EX[i],S)>0 then Result:=false;
end;
```

Comment: @KodiakSU, В принципе, я уже нашел решение, но за ответ - спасибо) Интересный способ, но мне не понятный. Можешь пояснит на чем он основан? зачем считать число символов АИОТаиот?

Comment: @АлександрЪ, Я малость переосмыслил, подправил и убрал лишнее. Старый вариант KOI8 работал только на больших текстах, а на мелких давал погрешности. "АИОТаиот" я брал как символы, статистически наиболее распространенные в русских текстах. Но идея себя не оправдала. Гораздо проще и эффективнее смотреть соотношение русских символов в верхнем и нижнем регистре(эффективно, если только текст набран не капсом или "заборчиком"). Если работа идет с цельнокодированным в KOI8 куском текста, то можно еще смотреть на регистры первых двух символов.